# java.util.ArrayDeque vs kotlin.collections.ArrayDeque

Tags: java, kotlin

I was trying to solve the advent of code 2021 challenge day 10 in Kotlin when I needed to use a stack. After finding out that you shouldnt use `Stack` anymore but `ArrayDeque` instead I got provided with two options: `java.util.ArrayDeque` and `kotlin.collections.ArrayDeque`. I tried out both but only the Java one acted like intended (`stack.push()`, `stack.pop()`, etc). The Kotlin one does not provide those methods.

So I was wondering which one I should use in which case.

Comment: "The Kotlin one does not provide those methods." -- Sure it does, it just doesn't call them by those names.  [`addFirst`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-deque/add-first.html) and [`removeFirst`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-deque/remove-first.html) add and remove elements from the head of the Deque just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin methods that resemble the required operations are

1. Stack.push = [addLast()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-deque/add-last.html)
2. Stack.pop = [removeLast()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-deque/remove-last.html)

Comment: Alright, I get that the method names are different but why are those two different in first place?

Comment: @René In java, `ArrayDeque` inherits these methods from [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html). But Kotlin, the corresponding methods are available only in `ArrayDeque` (it inherits only List specific methods). I don't have much knowledge on the reasons for this name choice. Happy New Year :)

Comment: The Java class also defines the `addLast`, etc. names. And in my mind, those are less ambiguous, to be fair. Once you have a two-sided container, the push/pop/enqueue/dequeue/shift/unshift/etc metaphors start to get confusing. A clear-cut `addLast` and `removeLast` makes it quite plain and obvious which side is being interacted with.

Comment: If you look at the docs for the `Deque` interface (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html) you'll see they refer to e.g. ``pop()`` as the *`Stack` method*, and `removeFirst()` as the *equivalent `Deque` method*. So at a guess, the `Stack` methods are included for backwards compatibility because `Deque` is meant to be used as a drop-in replacement - but the "real" methods are the `Deque` ones, which are mirrored in the Kotlin implementation. Kotlin doesn't bother with the "pretend it's a stack" methods - it's a queue and you can just use one end of it!

Comment: You actually only need a MutableList to be able to call add() and removeLast() for the stack functionality. ArrayDeque is useful when you need a queue, O(1) complexity to add or remove at both start and end.